# find best way to save some word with idf and count

Tags: c#, .net

I have one text and a lot of sentences .all sentences  stored in the database with a specific id.
I want to read these sentences and save every word in the sentence so that I can finally find the number of repetitions of words throughout the text.

for example :

text = "The Keldholme Priory election dispute occurred in Yorkshire, England, in 1308. The Archbishop of York, William Greenfield, appointed one of the nuns to lead the house after a series of resignations by its prioresses. His candidate, Emma de Ebor', was deemed unacceptable by many nuns, and she resigned three months later. The Archbishop next appointed Joan de Pykering from nearby Rosedale Priory, but the nuns resisted her as well. The Archbishop attempted to quash the nuns' rebelliousness, exiling some to surrounding priories and threatening others with excommunication. The convent was not deterred, and eventually Greenfield allowed the nuns to elect one of their number again. They first re-elected Emma de Stapleton, who had been prioress in 1301, but she also became unpopular, and resigned. They eventually re-elected Emma de Ebor'. The election dispute evaporated, and little more was heard of the priory until its dissolution in 1536";

sentences = {"The Keldholme Priory election dispute occurred in Yorkshire, England, in 1308. The Archbishop of York, William Greenfield, appointed one of the nuns to lead the house after a series of resignations by its prioresses.","His candidate, Emma de Ebor', was deemed unacceptable by many nuns, and she resigned three months later.",...}

{word,count, idf} = {"The", 10,1000},{"Keldholme ", 1,9000},....

word = All words in all sentences.

count = Number of repeated words in all sentences.

idf = log(count_all_word/count_This_word).

My estimate is that we have about 140K non-repetitive words.

My test solution :

```
    public class TermModel
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
    public double idf { get; set; }
    public int count { get; set; }

}

    List<TermModel> termlist = new List<TermModel>();
    foreach (var item in sentences)
    {
      var cleanitem = cleanSen(item);//Output lists all sentence words
       foreach (var items in cleanitem)
       {
          var term = termlist.FirstOrDefault(p => p.text == items);
             if (term != null)
             {
                term.count++;
             }
             else
             {
              TermModel termModel = new TermModel();
              termModel.idf = 0;
              termModel.text = items;
              termModel.count = 1;
              termlist.Add(termModel);
              }
            }
       }

       int countALL = termlist.Count();
       foreach (var item in termlist)
       {
         item.idf = Math.Log(countALL / item.count);
       }
       foreach(var item in termlist)
       {
          _db.termModels.Add(item);
       }
          _db.SaveChanges();
```

**This method takes more than 30 minutes to complete**

I need a better way

- save in database is not required
- I use the sqlite
- save is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I followed what you want up until the log business. Dictionary are very fast the can be altered to hold 2 billion items. I think they use hash tables underneath. So this might speed up getting the count.

```
    private void CountWords()
    {
        string text = "The Keldholme Priory election dispute occurred in Yorkshire, England, in 1308. The Archbishop of York, William Greenfield, appointed one of the nuns to lead the house after a series of resignations by its prioresses. His candidate, Emma de Ebor', was deemed unacceptable by many nuns, and she resigned three months later. The Archbishop next appointed Joan de Pykering from nearby Rosedale Priory, but the nuns resisted her as well. The Archbishop attempted to quash the nuns' rebelliousness, exiling some to surrounding priories and threatening others with excommunication. The convent was not deterred, and eventually Greenfield allowed the nuns to elect one of their number again. They first re-elected Emma de Stapleton, who had been prioress in 1301, but she also became unpopular, and resigned. They eventually re-elected Emma de Ebor'. The election dispute evaporated, and little more was heard of the priory until its dissolution in 1536";
        char[] sp = new[] { ' ' };
        string[] words = text.Split(sp);
        Dictionary<string, int> WordCount = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        char[] punctuation = new[] { ',', '.' }; //probably need to more punctuation characters
        foreach (string word in words)
        {
            string CleanWord =word.Trim(punctuation);
            CleanWord = CleanWord.ToLower();
            if (WordCount.ContainsKey(CleanWord))
            {
                WordCount[CleanWord]++;
            }
            else
            {
                WordCount.Add(CleanWord, 1);
            }
        }
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> kv in WordCount)
        {
            Debug.Print($"{kv.Key} {kv.Value}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: how save Dictionary to use another time